# WordPress Bootstrap dynamic carousel showing images separately not as carousel

Tags: images

[image]

I am trying to add dynamic WordPress-bootstrap carousel by category. It is showing images but not as carousel. All images are aligned vertically. Second, url is not working also.

Please help me to integrate properly. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code

```
<?php

 $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=33&posts_per_page=3' );

if( $catquery->have_posts() ): ?>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
      <!--Twitter bootstrap Photo carousel-->
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide center-block"  data-ride="carousel" >
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <?php while( $catquery->have_posts() ) : $catquery->the_post(); $index++ ?>

      <?php if ( $index == 1 ): ?>
        <div class="item active">
      <?php else: ?>
        <div class="item">
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id() ); ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        </div>
        </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div><!-- carousel ends here -->
```

Comment: What URL is not working - the image URLs?

Comment: You might need to manually initialize the carousel as well. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#via-javascript

Comment: i have added the image, which i am having issue.

Answer (score -1):

it seems that all sliders not active
you must first assign value to $index = 1 before loop
then in the end of loop it increase before endwhile $index++